# Как достать JSON объекты из файла средствами JSON path

Tags: json

Всем привет.
Вопрос такой:
У меня есть файл в котором строка за строкой записаны валидные  JSON. К примеру:

```
{"id":"1"}
{"id":"2"}
и так далее
```

Парсинг происходит при помощи JSON Path.
Если я пытаюсь достучаться до элементов id через:

```
&.id
```

То в ответ получаю пустую строку.
Однако если в файле содержится лишь одна JSON-валидная строка данный метод выдает правильный результат.

Как правильно прочесть нужные данные из файла когда присутствуют все строки?

**UPD** [пример json(в принципе это твиты)](http://pastebin.com/tgx4MMrn)

Comment: Добавь в вопрос валидный `json`.

Comment: Добавил ссылку на пример json

Comment: Может, дело в том, что валидные json строка за строкой вместе образуют невалидный JSON? попробуйте обернуть содержимое файла в [] и расставить запятые .replace( '\n' , ',')

Comment: А можно сделать тоже самое без перезаписывания файла? У меня их скопилось очень даже много.

Comment: Я загуглил JSON Path, чтоб узнать что за зверь такой, и у меня глаза разбежались. Что вы используете кроме JSON Path? Какое окружение? Язык?

Comment: @Darth Использую Talend Open Studio. В нем парсинг JSON осуществляется через JSONPath или Xpath.

Comment: @UNIm95, используйте валидный JSON и все будет работать.